# Is this worst-case analysis correct for this piece of code?

Tags: algorithm, analysis

```
int a = 0;  //1 unit
for (int b = 0; b < N; b++) // (1 + N + N) = 2n + 1
    for (int c = b+2; c > 0; c--) //2 + (N+1) + N = 2N+3
        a += b*c; //3 units
```

Yields: `1 + (2n+1)(2n+3) = 4n^2+8n+4`

I'm new to algorithm analysis and I'm not 100% sure this is correct. Can anyone help me out and let me know if I'm doing this right? And if not, point out where I went wrong.

Pretty much I calculated the worst case running time to be `4n^2+8n+4`

Comment: Normally, a loop is considered O(n), rather than calculating it as `2n+1` . Where did you get the 2n from ?

Comment: It's wrong. It should be something more like `1 + N * (N/2 * 3) = O(N²)`.

Comment: You can read up on [Big O nation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) if you don't know what the O(•) part is about.

Comment: in the comments i put how many units each part of the for loops takes and I added it up, im assuming thats wrong now, so the first loops is just N and then the second loop inside is (3N/2)? I get how you got the 1 + N but the last part (N/2 * 3) can you explain how you calculated that? thankyou :)

Comment: Your inner loop does `3` units per iteration, and the value of `b` is going to average about `N/2`, so you get `N` iterations for the outer loop, times `N/2` iterations for the inner loop, times `3` for the `a+=b*c` part.

Comment: this is all so confusing for me lol, ill read further into this and then try to re-read your response and see if it makes any sense :D thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider your code,

```
for (int b = 0; b < N; b++)
    for (int c = b+2; c > 0; c--) 
        a += b*c;
```

The outer loop is executed `N` times where as the inner loop is executed `b+2` times for each iteration of the outer loop.

Thus the statement `a += b*c;` is executed for a total of `2 + 3 + 4 + ... + N+2` times.

Thus the instruction is executed for a total of `([1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N+2] - 1)` times.

It is equal to `[(N+2)(N+3)]/2-1` because the sum of first N integers is `N(N+1)/2`.

There for the complexity of the given piece of code is  **Θ(((N<sup>2</sup>+5N+6)/2) - 1)** which is just **Θ(N<sup>2</sup>)**.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop executes b+2 times for each value of b in the outer loop. So the total number of times the inner loop executes is equal to (2 + 3 + 4 + .... + (N+2)). Each time it performs 3 units of work. So total time the inner loop executes is [ ((N+2) (N+3)/2 ) - 1 ] * 3 .

But generally we measure running time asymptotically and this comes to Big O (N ^ 2)

Comment: thankyou! its getting late, ill analysis this again in the morning!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when using [big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), the coefficients are ignored, and the algorithm is classified by its fastest-growing function. In this case, you have two `O(n)` loops, which are nested. The nesting is multiplicative, giving the algorithm `O(n²)` aka 'quadratic' complexity. The Wikipedia articles on [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and [computational complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) may give you a starting point for further reading.

Comment: thanks for the links :) Im gonna get some rest then read up on it so i can think on a clear mind!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to say that the statement in the inner loop takes 3 units, then the inner loop takes ( b + 2 ) * 3 units. Now, if we let b range from 0 to N - 1 and sum, we get

( 0 + 2 ) * 3 + ( 1 + 2 ) * 3 + (2 + 2) * 3 + ... + ( 2 + N - 1 ) * 3

= 3 * ( 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + ( N + 1 ) )

= 3 * ( ( 1 + 2 + ... + N+1 ) - 1)

= 3 * ( ( ( N +1 ) ( N + 2 ) / 2 ) - 1 )

= 3 * ( N^2 + 3*N + 2 - 2 ) / 2

= 3/2 * N^2 + 9/2 * N

Note that I didn't count the operations performed in the loop headers as operations, this typically isn't done. In fact one would usually just count the most expensive operation that is performed the most number of times ( in this case the multiplication ).

By the way, I used the fact that the sum of the first n integers is n ( n+ 1 ) / 2

Comment: One can compute the exact number of operations needed ( which is what it seemed like you were trying to do and is what I did as well ), but as others have said the more useful approach here is to consider its big O complexity : which is O(n^2)

Comment: so what youre trying to say is that i can ignore: " a += b*c;" in my calculation?

Comment: Well no, don't ignore it, recognize that that's the basic operation dominating the complexity of this algorithm and then try to figure out how many times it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your example:

```
int a = 0;  // 1

for (int b = 0; b < N; b++) // 1 + (N+1) + N
{
    for (int c = b+2; c > 0; c--) // 1 + (((N+2)*(N+3)/2)+1) + ..) * N
    {
        a += b*c; // 3 * ((N+2)*(N+3)/2) * N
    }
}
```

Doing the math we get:

```
= 1 + 1 + (N+1) + N + 1 + [(((N+2)*(N+3)/2)+1) + ((N+2)*(N+3)/2)) * N] + [3 * ((N+2)*(N+3)/2) * N]

= 4 + 2 N + 1/2 N^3 + 3 N^2 + 11/2 N + 4 + 9 N + 15/2 N^2 + 3/2 N^3

= 8 + 33/2 N + 21/2 N^2 + 2 N^3
```

Giving us `O(N^3)`